# request.get returns a subset

Tags: python, python-requests

The code I am using is:

```
import requests
k=requests.get('https://zebramo.com/search/product-scope/merrell?extended=true&is_sold=false&include_vacation=false&max_price=100&order_by=price&order_direction=asc',headers=headerZ,stream=True)
m=k.content
print(m)
```

When I check the page in Google Chrome ==>Inspect ==> Network I see that the return variable  I get matches the first "Response" of the URL, but the responses or the outputs of .js files underneath do not exist within my content m.
Because the same URL works in the Google Chrome, I tried to make a not-very-informed effort replicating the various headers info from the browser with no success.

(In case there is not a straight answer I will also appreciate recommendations on the right direction, thanks.)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If one would enter the URL in the second line to a browser a page will open. Assuming I can get the html (so the text) of this page thru request.get; I have created above code. But if I (you) run the code, the content of the response does not include all the text (html) of the page linked to this URL.

Comment: If I still could not make myself clear,,, maybe running the code and comparing the return of request.get.content() with the actual html rendered through a browser+(same URL), could make my issue clearer.